# Incorporating button into Servo Loop

Tags: arduino

I am extremely new so please bare with me. I am attempting to control a servo by both the internal timer and by button. Essentially the servo will open a door for 6 seconds every 24 hours or so OR if you press the button [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr6GL.jpg)

The loop for the timer works but the button doesn't. However if i just upload the button code it works fine. Help please! Even better if the servo could go to 180 when the button is held down and return to 0 when released would be ideal.

Here is my code. Tell me where I messed up please!

```
    #include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;
const int BUTTON_PIN = 8;
const int SERVO_PIN  = 9;

int angle = 0;          // the current angle of servo motor
int lastButtonState;    // the previous state of button
int currentButtonState; // the current state of button

void setup(){
  myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
Serial.begin(9600); 
 pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
 myservo.write(angle);
  currentButtonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
  } 
  
void loop(){

  myservo.write(0);// move servos to center position -> 90°
  delay(18000);
   myservo.write(180);// move servos to center position -> 120°
  delay (6000);

  lastButtonState    = currentButtonState;      // save the last state
  currentButtonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN); // read new state

  if(lastButtonState == HIGH && currentButtonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("The button is pressed");

    // change angle of servo motor
    if(angle == 180)
      angle = 0;
    else
    if(angle == 0)
      angle = 180;

    // control servo motor arccoding to the angle
    myservo.write(angle);
  }
}
```

Comment: put the first 4 lines of the loop() in a condition which allows them to run only every 24 hours. now write(0) executes immediately after write(angle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your picture your pins should be 7 and 9.  Basically, the only issue with your code is that you can not use delay if you also want to be monitoring something (your button).  So instead you use what is called a watchdog timer, where you basically make something happen ever so often based on the system clock, but then also remain available to do other things when that is not happening.

Comparing the blink and blink without delay examples in the arduino example sketch folder may help explain this concept further.

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;
const int BUTTON_PIN = 7;
const int SERVO_PIN  = 9;

unsigned long dayTimer_ms = 0;
unsigned long autoOpenDelay_ms = 86400000;

int angle = 0; 

void setup(){
  myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  myservo.write(0);
}

void loop() {

  if(millis() - dayTimer_ms > autoOpenDelay_ms )
  {
    dayTimer_ms = millis();
    myservo.write(180); //(open?)
    delay(6000);
    myservo.write(0);
  }
  
  if(millis()<dayTimer_ms)//overflow handling (in case this runs for more than 50 days straight)
  {
    dayTimer_ms = millis();
  }
  
  if (!digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) && angle != 180)
  {
    angle = 180;
    myservo.write(angle);
  }

  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) && angle != 0)
  {
    angle = 0;
    myservo.write(angle);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really close! However in testing it with a 10 second delay instead of 24 hours, the servo doesn't go back to 180 again unless I hit the button again. Any ideas on incorporating the button control/overide open in addition to the 24 hour open cycle?

Comment: is 180 open and 0 close? or is that backwards?

Comment: WOW completely misread your goal, gimme a bit and I will update the code.

Comment: THIS IS ABSOLUTELY AMAZING! Thank you so much!

Comment: You really saved me here. Simply brilliant. Can I ask why you had to put "dayTimer_ms = millis();" before "myservo.write(180);"

Comment: ofc, basically what that is doing is saving the time right now into a variable (dayTimer_ms) so that the event will not trigger again until current time (millis())  is the specified time interval (autoOpenDelay_ms) higher than the last time the event triggered (which you saved in that variable).  So its like when the thing happens you take a snap shot of a clock hand, then you keep comparing that picture to the live clock, when the live clock's hand has traveled your target distance away from the hand in the picture, you activate your event and take a new snapshot.

Comment: OK I have question for you if you find the time. I am attempting to add a second servo and button. Instead of a timer, the second button will be activated by a water level sensor. Like the other servo it can also be activated via the press of a button. Even when I remove the water level sensor code, button A activates the servo but not in the way I want it to.

Comment: Throw it up as a new question (same thing state your goal, what code you currently have and why it isnt working).  I will keep an eye out for your new question and try to help.